# IDE for MEAN stack [ MongoDb,Express,AngularJs,NodeJs ]

Tags: mean-stack

For designing the MEAN stack application, I am creating separate modules( angularjs,expressjs,nodejs,mongodb) and i am linking them manually. Can you please suggest me an IDE available for directly designing MEAN stack application.

Comment: see this one Brackets.io

Comment: sublime too is a 1 of the many best options available

Comment: http://codecondo.com/best-ide-for-node-js/ is a pretty good outline. Also take a look at Visual Studio Code https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These topics on Stack Overflow usually get flagged as contentious or something after a while. However I thought I would share my own experience of using JavaScript IDEs under Windows.

I was using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), however my dev box is ageing a bit and PyCharm is too heavy for it. Besides, as the name implies, it's really for Python, in fact I started using it for Django.

If I could afford [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and a box to run it on, I'd definitely check that out :)

I fell back on the default at my workplace, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). However the linter add-on is a bit clunky, and it has real difficulty rendering JavaScript in HTML.

For now I am satisfied with my recent discovery of [brackets.io](http://brackets.io/). It does have an early days feel to it, but I find it's code completion particularly useful, and once I got an add-on to use JSHint instead of JSLint it chimes very well with the [meanjs](http://meanjs.org/) code I'm learning from. Meanjs uses [swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) templating, which parses as straight HTML so there's no problem there, but if you're wedded to a particular template module then you should look for an IDE that supports it, either directly or via add-ons. Brackets.io seems to have quite a lively add-on community at the moment.